# Oracle regexp pattern matching instances of a but not ab

Tags: regex, oracle, regex-negation

I have seen from from oracle documentation I can do a|b which will match all instances of character 'a 'or character 'b'. I wondered if it was possible in regexp to have 'a' and not 'b' e.g. match all instances of 'a' except where a is followed by 'b'.

so with these 3 strings

1. AAAA
2. ACAD
3. AAAB

I want to match 1 and 2 but not 3.

Comment: doesn't #3 (AAAB) match where A is followed by a non-B? (the first AA part)

Comment: 'a' and not 'b' is quite different from "except where 'a' is **followed** by 'b'". The string 'ba' does not satisfy the condition [ 'a' and not 'b' ] because it does have a 'b', but it does not come **after** 'a'. Please clarify. Also, if you really meant "follow" - does that mean **immediately** follow, or does it mean "follow *somewhere* later in the string, not necessarily **immediately** after 'a'"?

Comment: You just need to check if there is no `AB` in the string, `col NOT LIKE '%AB%' AND col LIKE '%A%'`

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
with x as (
  select 'AAAA' as str from dual
  union all
  select 'ACAD' as str from dual
  union all
  select 'AAAB' as str from dual
)
select * from x
where regexp_like(str, '[aA][^bB]')
and NOT regexp_like(str, '[aA][bB]')
```

Output:

```
AAAA
ACAD
```

Note:  If you don't care if A is followed by some other non-B char, you can simply do:

```
with x as (
  select 'AAAA' as str from dual
  union all
  select 'ACAD' as str from dual
  union all
  select 'AAAB' as str from dual
)
select * from x
where regexp_like(str, '[aA]')
and NOT regexp_like(str, '[aA][bB]')
```

which would match "AAAA" or "XYZA"

Comment: The first condition in WHERE is not excessive; the OP didn't say he needs an A followed by something else. Indeed, the A can be at the end of the string (or even, the entire string can be 'A').